# Change between images with a Button

Tags: android, imageview

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to change the content of an `ImageView` with a button and if I press the button again the image changes back. I thought it would be easy with an `if-else` statement but I have been looking around in the `ImageView` API and I don't see the method that allows me to get the image that is being displayed in that moment... Any ideas? 
Here is my code so far...

```
boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
       imagen.setImageResource(R.mipmap.imag1);

    }
});
```

I didn't copy the rest of the code because I dont think it's necessary

Comment: what the log says? do you have any mistake?

Comment: I would set the onclick to the XML, not in the Java.  If you need to get to another image look up how TAG works.  It's better than trying to muck the the ID.

Comment: you need change imageView background when you press button to show interactive click?

Comment: I have 2 images, 1 as default lets say imag0 and a second one imag1, the ImageView displays imag0 as default, but once I click the button I want to change the ImageView displayed image to imag1, and if I click again the button the ImageView should display imag0 again... I cant use onclick attribute XML. The app is working fine, I just need a way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image of the button with using this method:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imagen.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

To set image of a button with another bitmap you can use:

```
imagen.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```